# How can I have the Mighty Mouse's secondary button on the left in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, boot-camp, mighty-mouse

I use Windows 10 on a Mac Mini running Boot Camp. My mouse is a wired Mighty Mouse connected via the keyboard USB. The secondary button (used to bring up the context menu) is, by default, on the right.

By design, the secondary button can only be clicked if no other part of the front half of the mouse is being touched. Since I use the mouse left-handed, this requires me to arch my entire hand over the mouse while trying to hold it steady from the other side — an intensely uncomfortable gesture.

Under OS X, the side of the secondary button can be switched to be on the left. How do I switch the side under Windows 10?

Comment: In Windows of old, one would use the [Mouse control panel](http://i.imgur.com/o8i8jUw.png) to switch the primary and secondary mouse buttons. I don't have a Mighty Mouse handy to see if that works, but have you given it a try?

Comment: Quickest way path to the Control Panel these days is to right click (ha!) the Start button on the taskbar, and select Control Panel (or Win+X then P)

Comment: You can also do this in the Windows 10 Settings app by navigating to `Devices` > `Mouse & touchpad`.

Comment: @AshleySteel - all that does is make the awkward-tiny-upper-right-corner the primary, and the main surface area of the mouse the secondary. There should be a way to make the tiny-upper-left-corner the secondary and the main surface area remain the primary.

Comment: I guess you'll need drive software specifically from Apple that is able to do that, then. For example, my Logitech mouse has this (as I also use my mouse left handed): https://imgur.com/uhx2kri . Have you tried asking/emailing Apple Support or a Genius in-store?

Comment: @AshleySteel It's out of the support period. Cheaper to just buy a real mouse.

Comment: Might indeed be the case. If you're after an ambidextrous mouse, I can recommend the Logitech M510.